# Common Data Utils is there such a thing?

Tags: java

I find myself quite often in development doing things like creating constants/enums for common data like states, state abbreviations, countries, languages, mime-types, time_zones...etc...etc...

Is there a project out there that has a collection of these things?  I've seen them scattered in different packages, I thought it would be handy to pull in a package that covered 80% of what I needed.

Comment: Perhaps you should write one.  Note: the states are different in each country.

Comment: I was thinking that same thing, but wanted to know if something like that existed first.

Comment: I think one would have to be huge and thus not practical. For example time handling in joda time is elegant but big library, I wouldn't want to combine that with other libraries. Money handling is like that as well. Countries, languages, timezones already exist in base java.

Answer (score 1):

[javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/activation/MimetypesFileTypeMap.html) and friends is a standard library for dealing with mime types.

[java.util.TimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) can be used for getting access to available time zones.

[java.util.Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) can be used to access a country related information.

Know thy Java Libraries!

Answer (score 1):

**Time**

[JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/%20%22JodaTime) - common used Time API.

[Time in Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) - new JDK 8 DateTime API. Very similar to Joda.

**Money**

[JodaMoney](http://joda-money.sourceforge.net/userguide.html) -common Money API